# How do you populate the host for image_url helper in a mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the asset host specified in my Rails 5.2.0 config:

`config.action_controller.asset_host = "assets.example.com"`

But the `image_url` helper still only returns the path without the host. I am using `<%= image_url('/something') %>` in my mailer view file. Whenever it renders it just uses the path `"/images/something"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config.action_controller.asset_host` setting will only affect the asset host in your views. To set it in your mailer, try:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://stage.example.com"
```

Comment: Yeah, I can hack it, but according to the docs I should be able to set it. I don't believe its being overridden since i can set it explicitly in the console and still get only the path.

Comment: Your console session will still be running an env, try calling Rails.env from there and checking config/environments/development.rb if it's dev

Comment: I added some more info to the question. Any clues?

Comment: It looks like the host part only gets added inside of a view and will never appear in console: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10051

Comment: I ran into the issue because the url wasn't showing in my mailer preview. Maybe their is a bug with that?

Comment: You never mentioned the mailer part :) Will update my answer

Comment: Yeah, I tried to simplify the question. I've updated it now.

Comment: The above should work for you fingers crossed, the mailer needs a specific config setting

Comment: And you'll need to restart the server for config settings to take effect

Comment: ‍♂️That was it! You may want to clean up your answer or post a new one and I can accept it for the next person who misses this!

Comment: Glad we got there :)